# Extensions of probability measures on fields

Tags: probability-theory

I am trying to solve exercise 3.3 in Billingsley's "Probability and measure" and I am not sure I correctly understood the text. I am not going to copy all the text, but I will ask directly some questions.

Some background:

Let P be a probability measure on the field $F_0$ and $P^*$ be the outer measure defined for each subset A of $\Omega$ as $P^*(A)=inf \sum_n P(A_n)$, where $A \subset \cup_n A_n$.
A theorem (3.1 in Billingsley) guarantees that $P^*$ is the unique probability measure on the $\sigma$-field $\sigma(F_0)$ such that $P^*(B)=P(B)$ for each $B \in F_0$.

Now the questions:

1) If $\Omega$ is uncountable and $F_0$ is the field of finite and cofinite sets, and P(A)=0 if A is finite and P(A)=1 if A is cofinite, do $P^*$ (defined as above) and $P$ agree on $F_0$?

My answer: P is a probability measure on $F_0$ (it is possible to check that it is countably additive) and then theorem 3.1 holds and P and $P^*$ agree on $F_0$.
My doubt comes from the fact that the text of the exercise seems to suggest that this is not the case and to explain why...

2) If \Omega is uncountable and F_0 is the field of countable and cocountable  sets, and P(A)=0 if A is countable and P(A)=1 if A is cocountable, do $P^*$ (defined as above) and P agree on $F_0$?

My answer would be the same than before:
P is a probability measure on $F_0$ (it is possible to check that it is countably additive) and then theorem 3.1 holds and P^* agree on $F_0$.

3) Let $P(A)=I_A(\omega_0)$ for $A \in F_0$, and assume that ${\omega_0} \in \sigma(F_0)$, do $P^*$ (defined as above) and P agree on $F_0$?

My answer would be the same than before:
P is a probability measure on $F_0$ (it is possible to check that it is countably additive) and then theorem 3.1 holds and $P^*$ agree on $F_0$.
In this case I do not understand also why the text specifies that ${\omega_0} \in \sigma(F_0)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to 1 and 2 will be very similar since an uncountable set is never the union of a countable number of finite or countable sets. In this case, if $A$ is finite/countable, then $A \subset \cup A_n$ where for every $n$, $A_n = A$. Therefore $P^*(A) \leq \sum 0 = 0$. Since $P^*(A) \geq 0$ then you see that $P^*(A) = P(A) = 0$. On the other hand, if $B$ is a cofinite/cocountable set, then because $\Omega$ is uncountable, it must be that $B$ is uncountable. So if $A_n \in F_0$ such that $B \subset \cup A_n$ then for at least one of the $n$, $A_n$ must be uncountable (as remarked in the first sentence) which means that for this $n$, $P(A_n) = 1$ (since $A_n$ must in fact then be cofinite/cocountalbe). Therefore you will find that $P^*(B) \geq 1$. Choosing $A_1 = B$ and $A_n = \varnothing$ for $n >1$, you get $\sum P(A_n) = 1 \geq P^*(B)$, so $P^*(B) = 1 = P(B)$.

If the assumption on the first problem was that $\Omega$ is countable, then $P^*$ and $P$ won't agree on $F_0$. This happens since if $A \in F_0$ is cofinite, then $A$ is countable and we can denumerate the elements of $A=\{a_1, a_2, ...\}$. Now, for each $i$, $\{a_i\} \in F_0$ and  $\cup\{a_i\} = A$. But then $0 \leq P^*(A) \leq \sum P(\{a_i\}) = 0$, so $P^*(A)=0$ while $P(A)=1$. What you should notice here is that since $A$ is the countable disjoint union of the $\{a_i\}$, you find that $1 = P(A) = P(\cup\{a_i\}) \neq \sum P(\{a_i\}) = 0$. So, $P$ is not a very nice candidate for a premeasure.

For question 3, we have $P(A)=1$ if $\omega_0 \in A$, otherwise $P(A) = 0$. If $A \subset \cup A_n$ and $\omega_0 \notin A$ then we can choose $A_n = A$ for every $n$ to find $P^*(A) = P(A) = 0$ using similar arguments as before. On the other hand, if $\omega_0 \in A$ and $A \subset \cup A_n$, then there is some $n$ such that $\omega_0 \in A_n$. Therefore you can infer that $P^*(A) \geq 1$. Since you can choose $A_1 = A$ and $A_n = \varnothing$ for every $n > 1$, you find that $P^*(A) \leq 1$ implying that $P^*(A) = P(A) =1$.

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for your answer. I agree with what you are writing but: a) If I check that the hypotheses of theorem 3.1 are verified, it follows from the theorem itself that P* is the only possible extension of P and it has the same value on all the set of the field. Using theorem 3.1 makes my answer shorter than yours. b) the text of the exercise suggests that it is not possible to extend P in these cases, while I think there is no problem (and your reasoning confirms it) c) in the third question, why is it required that $\omega_0$ belongs to $\sigma(F_0)$?

Comment: a) It's good that the theorem gives you an easier track (a reaffirmation that theorems can make life easier!). b) I looked up the question and the pieces you ask are just 3 parts of a 6 part question in which the text asks you to decide which of the 6 cases will have $P^*$ agree with $P$ on $F_0$ and which ones will not. This doesn't suggest to me that all of the parts won't agree. c) I'm not completely sure why he required $\{\omega_0\} \in F_0$. Perhaps so that functions on $\Omega$ can disagree everywhere but $\omega_0$ and still be equal $P$-a.e.

Comment: Hi Tom, I probably misunderstood the text. I have still doubts on c), but thanks for the time you spent answering my questions!